# Registration - website crashes, error 403

Tags: user-registration

Some time ago I wrote new functionalities on the client's website. I wrote some of the code myself, some use plugins. After uploading the final version to the server, there was a problem registering new users. Virtually every time, when you try to log in to a new account, you get a 403 error. I undone all the changes I made and minimized plugins. I can't find the source of the problem, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a backup before any of your changes you can compare the current state too, e.g. the copy the client sent you before you started work? If you look at the new user account in the admin site (I assume you can still log in yourself?) is there anything wrong with them, e.g. missing roles, or their roles no longer have 'read' capability? Where do you get the 403 - on the admin home page, or on any specific page?

Comment: By "some use plugins" do you mean you may have modified WP Core code? You could try downloading the same version of Core that's installed and re-upload everything to make sure those changes are reverted. You might also be dealing with caching, either through a plugin or at the server level.